# Metamask always show '0' for gas price and value

Tags: transactions, metamask, ropsten, confirmations

I tried to deploy and execute some transactions on multiple contracts but Metamask keeps showing 0 for the gas price and value field. I am on Ropsten test network. It is not specific to any contract, it is occurring on almost all contracts. Does anyone know the fix or the cause?

See screenshot, the below transaction is actually asking for 0.002 ethers from the account but it shows 0 here.

[image]

Comment: How are you executing the transaction? Web3? Remix?

Comment: When I make deployment through remix, I face same issue. And when I execute write contract transactions through web3, same issue.

Comment: Have you tried doing it for other testnet? like rinkeby or kovan?

Comment: No I have only tested it on ropsten

Comment: Try doing the same but just change the testnet, If the problem persists, check the parameters you are passing for the send_transaction method. Like the gasPrice/gasLimit.